# three.js transformControls wrong position

Tags: javascript, three.js

I create a box by those code:

```
let v = [
            new THREE.Vector3(-100,30,10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-100,30,-10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-100,-10,10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-100,-10,-10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-110,30,-10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-110,30,10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-110,-10,-10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-110,-10,10)
        ];
        let f = [
            new THREE.Face3(0,2,1),
            new THREE.Face3(2,3,1),
            new THREE.Face3(4,6,5),
            new THREE.Face3(6,7,5),
            new THREE.Face3(4,5,1),
            new THREE.Face3(5,0,1),
            new THREE.Face3(7,6,2),
            new THREE.Face3(6,3,2),
            new THREE.Face3(5,7,0),
            new THREE.Face3(7,2,0),
            new THREE.Face3(1,3,4),
            new THREE.Face3(3,6,4)
        ];
        let g = new THREE.Geometry();
        g.mergeVertices();
        g.vertices = v;g.faces = f;
        let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000,side:THREE.DoubleSide});
        let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(g,m);
        scene.add(mesh);
```

then i use THREE.transformControls,but it didn't appear on the mesh,and always at the center of the scene
[image: wrong position]
if i need to set the box's matrix or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's better to translate your mesh, not its geometry.

```
let v = [
  new THREE.Vector3(5, 30, 10),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, 30, -10),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, -10, 10),
  new THREE.Vector3(5, -10, -10),
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, 30, -10),
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, 30, 10),
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, -10, -10),
  new THREE.Vector3(-5, -10, 10)
];
```

and then you just translate the mesh

```
mesh.position.x = -105;
```

UPD If is impossible to change vertices coordinates at the time of creation, then you can find the centroid of your geometry, then use `.center()` method and then translate your mesh to the position of the previously found centroid.

```
g.computeBoundingBox();
var centroid = new THREE.Vector3();
centroid.addVectors(g.boundingBox.min, g.boundingBox.max).divideScalar(2);
g.center();

...
mesh.position.copy(centroid);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/k0dmztfr/) example r87

Comment: thanks for your answer,I have tried your code,and transformControls helper is in the box.but the same problem,box's position has changed,it moved to the center of scene but that isn't what i want

Comment: i think problem is that,when i create a mesh,whatever it's vertices it's position is (0,0,0),and transformControls will appear at the mesh's position.but as we noticed the vertices,mesh's right position isn't(0,0,0),so the we'll see that the mesh isn't at "transformControls  position(0,0,0)".

Comment: Yes, correct. But it seems, that you mix up position of a mesh and coordinates of vertices  in its geometry. The first one relates to coordinate system of its parent (a scene or another object), the second one relates to the local coordinate system of the mesh itself.